# What is PHP Soaps multiCall equivalent to .NET call for Magento API v2

Tags: php, .net, magento

I happily connected an endpoint into my .NET project, made wrapper classes and everything is lovely jubbly..(i translated as much as possible using PHP tutorials) and i ran into a massive bottleneck that i am not really sure how to solve.. i cant ffind any decent information about this.

So....

In PHP i can use

```
$calls = array( 
    array( 'catalog_product.info', 166 ), 
    array( 'catalog_product.info', 167 ), 
    array( 'catalog_product.info', 168 ), 
); 
$results = $soap->multiCall( $session_id, $calls );
```

and in one call i will get 3 products saving me like 70% http overhead.

In .NET i use this

```
   Dim productReturn As MS.catalogProductReturnEntity
   Private myMagento As MS.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType = New MS.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient
   productReturn = myMagento.catalogProductInfo(SessionID, productId, storeView, requestAttr, Nothing)
```

and that returns one single item of extended information. The Service refence in .NET

```
Function catalogProductInfo(ByVal sessionId As String, ByVal product
As String, ByVal storeView As String, ByVal attributes As
MagentoBridge2.MS.catalogProductRequestAttributes, ByVal
productIdentifierType As String) As
MagentoBridge2.MS.catalogProductReturnEntity
Member of MagentoBridge2.MS.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType
```

Does not accept an array of products..

So how in .NET do use the `multiCall` that is used in the PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CLICK >[Some more details here](http://pkula.blogspot.com/2011/08/magento-php-and-visual-studio-net-using.html)

You need to put a PHP file on the root of your magento server that looks simething like this

```
<?php
$id_start = $_GET['start'];
$id_end = $_GET['end'];

// Magento login information 
$mage_url = 'http://www.YOURSITE.co.uk/api/?wsdl=1'; 
$mage_user = 'USERNAME'; 
$mage_api_key = 'PASSWORD'; 

// Initialize the SOAP client 
$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 

// Login to Magento 
$session_id = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );

    $calls = array(); 
    for ($id_start; $id_start <= $id_end; $id_start++)
        {
        array_push($calls, array( 'catalog_product.info', $id_start ));
        }

    $results = $soap->multiCall( $session_id, $calls ); 

    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Right! Simples!!!!!!!!!!!! Then in .NET you have a nice function like this!

```
Function getHTTPStream() As String
        Dim myh As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.YOURSITE.co.uk/prod.php?start=20&end=80")
        myh.Timeout = 30000
        myh.UserAgent = "Test"
        Dim myR As HttpWebResponse = myh.GetResponse()
        Dim myEnc As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
        Dim mySr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myR.GetResponseStream(), myEnc)

        Return mySr.ReadToEnd()
    End Function
```

Notice i pass `start=20` ; That is the ID it will start at and the `end=80`

### TADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa..

Now all you need to do in .NET is convert the JSON into a Table.. for example using [THIS](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)
And you know what! I can now request full extended information on items in about 100products per second in Visual Studio Freaking .NET! **Whoooooooooohoooooooooo!!** Before it took me 3 products a seconds doing individual calls in multi threaded requests.. What an improvement.

Thanks for every bodies help. (Crickets in the distance)